# Why, when I scale my data set, glmnet gives error?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, glmnet

I'm using glmnet for building the regression models.
My data are already log-transformed. when I scale my data set (zero mean, and SD=1), I get the following error:

```
Error in elnet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, type.gaussian,  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 5)
```

But without scaling data, glmnet run perfectly. 
would someone help me to understand why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

You most likely have NaN in your scaled data due to scaling of some columns with constant values (dividing by SD of zero), check the scaled data with is.na().

Comment: How can I scale to avoid  creating of NAs in data ?

Comment: Fixed my answer, meant to say "constant values", like all 1's, instead of "constant columns". If you scale a column with constant values, you get zero SD and divide by zero gives NaN. So remove these columns or set the NaNs to zero, these variables aren't predictive anyway.